# Marking only one answer as accepted

Tags: python, html, django, ajax, django-views

I am building a simple  Q&A site like Stack Overflow, and I am building marking an answer as accepted but when I implement it, it marks every answer as accepted. I mean User can accept any answer but I don't want this. I am trying to make - user can mark only one accepted answer. And if user marked one answer as accepted and tried to mark second as accepted then first will remove and second will be marked

models.py

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    answer_user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True)
    accepted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

views.py

```
def mark_accepted(request, question_id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Answer, pk=question_id)

    if request.GET.get('submit') == 'accept':
        if post.accepted == True:
            post.accepted = False
        else:
            post.accepted = True
    
    return JsonResponse({'action':'accept'})
```

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul the accept endpoint only seems to know which question, not which answer, so while that doesn't make sense given the OP's requirement it likely _is_ every answer getting accepted.

Comment: I'm not sure where my comment went, but again it seems like the problem is you've made whether or not an answer is accepted a property of the _answer_, so each one can individually be accepted or not, whereas if the requirement is "a question can have zero or exactly one accepted answer(s)" making which answer has been accepted a property of the _question_ would fit that much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it.

Firstly, Your `Answer` model should have a ForeignKey relationship with `Question` Model.

Like this

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    answer_user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True)
    accepted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

You should also pass in a `ans_id` in your `mark_as_accepted` view to uniquely identify the current answer that should be marked as accepted.

In your view,

- Query the Answer model and get the previously accepted answer (if any). Call it `prev_accepted_ans`.

  > `prev_accepted_ans = Answer.objects.filter(question=question_id, accepted=True)`
- Inside the else conditon in your view, you have to mark the previously accepted answer's (`prev_accepted_ans`) accepted attribute to False.

  > `prev_accepted_ans.update(accepted=False)`

```
def mark_accepted(request, question_id, ans_id):
    # Get the previously accepted answer (if any).
    prev_accepted_ans = Answer.objects.filter(question=question_id, accepted=True)
    
    # Get the answer that should be marked as accepted.
    post = get_object_or_404(Answer, id=ans_id)

    if request.GET.get('submit') == 'accept':
        if post.accepted == True:
            post.accepted = False
        else:
            # Mark the accepted attribute of prev_accepted_ans as False
            prev_accepted_ans.update(accepted=False)

            post.accepted = True
    
    return JsonResponse({'action':'accept'})
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your endpoint needs two parameters: question_id and answer_id.

Second, after you retrieve the answer by answer_id successfully, you should first update all accepted fields to false for all the records where question_id=question_id and accepted=true; then you should update the accepted field of the record where question_id=question_id and answer_id=answer_id to true.

NOTE: The Answer model needs a FK (question) to Question model. And its PK is answer_id.

Comment: Thanks for Suggestion, I also have a `FK` with `Question` model But How will i prevent that the user can mark only one accept answer ?

Comment: If you want only one accepted answer for each question, you need to implement the Second part of my answer. You should update the accepted field of other answers to false, and the accepted field of the current answer (the answer you retrieved) to true. This way the question always has one answer with accepted= true.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way of doing this would be adding accepted_answer field to the Question model itself!

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    answer_user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True)

class Question(models.Model):
    ...
    accepted_answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
```

now you just need to change accepted_answer in your Question model and everything will be fine!